# Two-way databinding, Silverlight and custom control / dependancy property

Tags: c#, silverlight

If I create an dependency property on a custom control that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.

For example with an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyCollection", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));

public IEnumerable<string> MyCollection
{
     get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(MyCollectionProperty); }
     set { SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value); }
}
```

If I databind an `ObservableCollection<T>` or `<string>` in this case to it. Does Silverlight take care of the two-way databinding for me?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'take care of the two-way databinding for me'.  In general two-way binding to collections is not a very good idea.  If you are just manipulating the existing collection then a one way binding works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) "In particular, if you are using OneWay or TwoWay (for example, you want your UI to update when the source properties change dynamically), you must implement a suitable property changed notification mechanism such as the INotifyPropertyChanged interface"

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements INotifyPropertyChanged for you. `IEnumerable<T>` does not. If you want easy two way binding simply bind to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, and change your `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`. XAML:

```
<ItemSource = "{Binding Path=MyCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```